# git clone with SSH not working suddenly :(

Tags: git, ssh

I have configured ssh key in git-swarm and it was working properly but its stopped working suddenly from today.

I have recreated the ssh key and configured the new one to GIT but it didn't help me.

could someone help me on this ?

Error while clone:

```
$ git clone git@gitswarm.test.com:webdev/comms.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/test/comms/.git/
Connection to gitswarm.test.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
$
```

I am debugging with -vvv option but I didn't get any valid error.

```
    $$ ssh -vvv  git@gitswarm.test.com

    ......
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

    debug3: channel 0: close_fds r 4 w 5 e 6
    Connection to gitswarm.test.com closed by remote host.
    Connection to gitswarm.test.com closed.
    Transferred: sent 2344, received 2736 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
    Bytes per second: sent 41835951.4, received 48832407.4
    debug1: Exit status -1
    $$
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you asked the administrator of `gitswarm.test.com`?

Comment: no @JonathonReinhart

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, May I know what needs to be check with administrator ?